# Get median from string of values

Tags: linux, string, bash, sorting, median

I need to find median of values saved in a string. I have to implement this in bash without any additional temporary files and I *cannot* use awk.

I have this string saved in `$string`:

```
85 13 4 45 1111 89 87 66 1 5 2 51 13 66 98 50 20 14 18 16 31 21 5175 12
```

First, I need to sort those values like this:

```
1 2 4 5 12 13 13 14 16 18 20 21 31 45 50 51 66 66 85 87 89 98 1111 5175
```

And then I need to find median of these values

```
(21+31) / 2 = 26
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any efficient way or command available in bash?

My idea:

To sort values, I could use `sort`, but I'm not sure how to force it to sort values from string, because it's using FILE.

I have no idea how to achieve median though, so I would appreciate small hint at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the numbers from the string into a sorted array, you can print them on a separate line each, pipe to `sort -n` and then read into an array with `mapfile`:

```
string='85 13 4 45 1111 89 87 66 1 5 2 51 13 66 98 50 20 14 18 16 31 21 5175 12'
mapfile -t arr < <(for num in $string; do echo "$num"; done | sort -n)
```

The `-t` option removes newlines from each value. Notice that you *cannot* pipe to `mapfile` because that would be in a subshell and `arr` would be empty afterwards.

It is usually a good idea to quote your variables, but in this case we rely on word spliting and must not quote `$string`.

Now, for the median, there are two options:

- There is an odd number of array elements and we just want the value of the middle element.
- There is an even number of array elements, and we want the mean of the two middle elements.

The number of array elements is `${#arr[@]}`, so we can check that and then decide what to do:

```
nel=${#arr[@]}
if (( nel % 2 == 1 )); then     # Odd number of elements
    val="${arr[ $((nel/2)) ]}"
else                            # Even number of elements
    val="$(( ( arr[$((nel/2))] + arr[$((nel/2-1))] ) / 2 ))"
fi
printf "%d\n" "$val"
```

This relies on integer arithmetics: if we have an odd number of elements, say three, the index of the median is 1 – which we get from integer division of three by two. For an even number of elements, say four, we want the elements at index 1 and 2, which we get by divding four by two for the higher index and subtracting one from it for the lower index.

If the two elements don't add up to an even number, the result will be rounded down. If that's not good enough, we can either check if the number is odd and manually add `.5` to the result, or we can use `bc` to do the calculation. Consider:

```
$ echo $(( 11/2 ))
5
$ bc <<< 'scale=1; 11/2'
5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands like the following:

```
str="85 13 4 45 1111 89 87 66 1 5 2 51 13 66 98 50 20 14 18 16 31 21 5175 12"
count=$(echo $str | wc -w)
arr=($(echo $str | tr " " "\n" | sort -n ))
#echo ${arr[*]}

if [[ $(( $count % 2 )) == 0 ]]; then 
    # even element count, get the elements around the middle
    f1=${arr[ $(( (count - 1 ) /2 )) ]}
    f2=${arr[ $(( (count + 1 ) /2 )) ]}
    #echo "f1=$f1, f2=$f2"
    echo $(( ($f1 + f2) / 2 )) 
else
    # odd element count
    echo ${arr[ $(( $count / 2 ))]}
fi
```